# Ripple effect in listView

Tags: android, listview, ripple

I have a listview which works fine, the ripple effect works on list item press . but I have added and used  [slide expandable list view](https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView) library to increase functionality of my listvview. Everything works fine but after adding the library the ripple on item click is not working

**getview ()of my list adapter**

```
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if(view == null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testlistitem,null);
        holder.listHeading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.beg_list_itemTextView);

        holder.listHash = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_hashtags);
        holder.alphabetList = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.beg_list_itemImageView);

        holder.favariteImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.favbtn);

        view.setTag(holder);

    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    CodeList codes = (CodeList) getItem(position);
    holder.listHeading.setText(codeList.get(position).getListHeading());
    holder.listHash.setText(codeList.get(position).getListHashText());
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(codeList.get(position).getAlphabetimg(),
                             holder.alphabetList);


    if (checkFavoriteItem(codes)) {
        holder.favariteImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite);
        holder.favariteImage.setTag("yes");
    } else {
        holder.favariteImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.unfavorite);
        holder.favariteImage.setTag("no");
    }                    


    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0){
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);

                //intent.putExtra("listheading",
                //       (codeList.get(position).getListHeading()));
                //intent.putExtra("alphabetimg",
                //              (codeList.get(position).getAlphabetimg()));

                intent.putExtra("demovideo",
                                (codeList.get(position).getDailogdemovideo()));


                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });     


    return view;
}
```

**mainactivity oncrate()**

```
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.inter_layoutListView);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new FinalAdapter(InterActivity.this,
                                      codelist);

        listview.setAdapter(new SlideExpandableListAdapter(adapter, R.id.expandbutton, R.id.expandable));
```

Comment: Please go through this link :

http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2015/12/Android-RecyclerView-Item-Click-Listener-Ripple-Effect.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+tutorialsbuzz+%28TutorialsBuzz%29

Comment: By the way, this is very ugly to use setOnclickListener inside each getView! Your code consumes a lot of memory!

Comment: @Vyacheslav I tried to implement onitemclicklistener in my mainactivity and found no ripple so tried this approach and still no ripple. By the way thanks for your advice. Didn't know that before

Comment: The Riple effect is based on the Layout of the Layout.I guess the lib you are using is either not inheriting from the proper classes, or overriding the style with something else.

Comment: @DanielBo I think the library is considerably old. So it might be over-riding the style. How can I change this?

Comment: @Vyacheslav If I implement the onitemclicklistener in main activity the iteclick does not work. So tried to place it in the getview method of my list adapter. Any suggestions how to make itemclick work if I place it in main activity

Comment: @user5524159 ok later. in two hours.

Comment: @user5524159 , ready

Comment: @Vyacheslav Waiting for your reply. I will try it and let you know. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ASummary extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

//.....
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ///...
adapter = new FinalAdapter(InterActivity.this,
                                      codelist,this);
///...
}
//....
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = (Integer) v.getTag();

      }

}
```

inside  `FinalAdapter` class create constructor and `OnClickListener` variable:

```
private OnClickListener listener;
FinalAdapter(Context ctx,codelist, OnClickListener listener ){

///super....

this.listener = listener;
}
```

then in `getView`:
use

```
view.setTag(position);
view.setOnClickListener(listener);
```